# How do I unlock an iPhone 6?

Tags: iphone, unlock

I recently bought the phone in Japan because it is way cheaper but then I am unable to use my local SIM card (Indonesia). Please anyone kindly assist and solve this (free method). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone is most likely carrier locked and unless you speak Japanese you might be out of luck. As for pricing this will depend on the carrier but have you tried different SIM cards and what country are you in?